# Are there any scripts to synchronize sites?

Tags: rsync, scripting, synchronization, cron

I've just set up a fail-over DNS to switch the site to a second host if the first is down. This is great for showing an old / archived version of the site, but I suspect maintenance is going to be a real pain.

I moved the files over with rsync in the first place. Is this the kinda thing that could be run as a cron job, automatically moving over newer files?

Answer (score 1):

Rsync was designed exactly for this sort of thing.  It will work great as a cron job.

To do a daily sync on the cron job:

```
$ crontab -e
Add line:
0 0 * * * [rsync command line]
```

Comment: Could you help me out with the exact line for the chron job? I'm not too familiar with this sort of thing...

Comment: Google "man crontab" for full details.